# Is $A^TA$ positive semi-definite for any real matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is written in title.

I read a theorem saying:

Suppose $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is symmetric. Then the following are equivalent.

1. $A$ is positive semidefinite.
2. Eigenvalues of $A$ are all non-negative.
3. $A$ can be factored as $A=G^TG$ where $G$ is an $p\times n$ matrix for some $p$.

The reason why I am asking is that I have a matrix $X$ and get some negative eigenvalues of $X^TX$ using either MatLab or R.

Comment: $A^\top A$ is always positive semi-definite. Simply consider the any vector $x$, and then $\langle A^\top Ax,x\rangle = \langle Ax,Ax\rangle = \|Ax\|^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: @YousufSoliman Semi-definite. A could be non-invertible.

Comment: @YousufSoliman (if $A$ is nonsingular)

Comment: You're both absolutely correct, my bad.

Comment: @YousufSoliman, Why is the first equality correct?

Comment: @Covvar Recall that the definition of the Euclidean inner product is given by $\langle x,y\rangle := x^\top y$. The first equality then follows from basic properties of the transpose and since matrix vector multiplication is associative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theorem is correct.  If $A$ is a real matrix, $A^T A$ is indeed positive semidefinite, and its eigenvalues are all nonnegative.  Matlab and R are using numerical methods, and roundoff error can cause some eigenvalues that should be $\ge 0$ to become negative.

For a simple example, let's suppose you're using floating-point decimal arithmetic with only two digits, and let $$ A = \pmatrix{41 & 29\cr 91 & 70\cr}$$
In exact arithmetic, $$A^T A = \pmatrix{9962 & 7559\cr 7559 & 5741\cr}$$
which is positive definite.  But since we're only using two-digit arithmetic, those entries have to be rounded.
The rounded version is
$$ \pmatrix{1.0 \times 10^4 & 7.6 \times 10^3\cr 7.6 \times 10^3 & 5.7 \times 10^3}$$
which is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.